# Angular - change one view ui.router

Tags: html, angularjs, task

I want create task manager but i don't know how do it.

i have 3 situaion:

1) tasks list in project:
left: list task, right: empty view with button "add task".
[image]

2) If I click edit task but left site is to same but right is form edit:
[image]

My actual code:

html:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div ui-view="view-tasks">loading...</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div ui-view="view-task">loading...</div>
</div>
```

And js:

```
...
$stateProvider.
      state('home', {
            url: "",
            views: {
                "view-tasks": {
                    templateUrl: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/app/template/tasks.html',
                    controller: 'TasksController'
                },
                "view-task": {
                    templateUrl: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/app/template/task.html',
                    controller: 'TasksController'
                }
            }
        }).
      state('task', {
            url: "/task/:id",
            views: {
                "view-tasks": {
                    templateUrl: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/app/template/tasks.html',
                    controller: 'TasksController'
                },
                "view-task": {
                    templateUrl: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/app/template/task.html',
                    controller: 'TaskController'
                }
            }
        })
    }]);
...
```

If I click edit that left list i refresh (what when i scrool etc? - bad).

how to solve this problem best?

mayby create function and in edit add: ng-click="editTask(id)" and automatic include new view with controller?

sorry for my english but i tryied :)

Comment: Both the views of your `home` state are the same (tasks.html)

Comment: i know, update answer :)

Comment: I think you should name your partial views differently. Left side `task-list` and right side `task-viewer`, something like that. The whole idea is to have unique names for your views. Doing it the way you did, the second partial view would just overwrite the first one.

Comment: do you have example code? I don't understand